# Using templates/jinja2 filter in Ansible playbook to conditionally execute certain

Tags: templates, ansible

I am creating a playbook for network device orchestration. I need to execute certain commands depending on the boolean vars input i receive.

Is it it possible to use the boolean input to populate the commands which need to be executed within one task? I prefer to use 1 task if possible.

In order to better explain what I am trying to achieve let me provide this example:

```
---

task: foo_netw_task
ios_config:
  provider: "{{ router_provider }}"
  lines:
    - "{{if bool_val_1 then 'command_1'}}"
    - "{{if bool_val_2 then 'command_2'}}"
    - "{{if bool_val_3 then 'command_3'}}"
```

So give the input below:

```
bool_val_1 = true, bool_val_2 = true, bool_val_3 = false
```

I would expect the executing playbook to look like this :

```
task: foo_netw_task
ios_config:
  provider: "{{ router_provider }}"
  lines:
    - 'command_1'
    - 'command_2'
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to omit list items in ansible.
However you can use a helper variable to select only the right entries:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
   bool_val_1: true
   bool_val_2: true
   bool_val_3: false
  tasks:
   - shell: "{{item}}"
     vars:
       tmp_lines:
         - "{{'echo command1' if bool_val_1 else None }}"
         - "{{'echo command2' if bool_val_2 else None }}"
         - "{{'echo command3' if bool_val_3 else None }}"
     loop: "{{tmp_lines|select()|list}}"

Output:

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [shell] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=echo command1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=echo command2)

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```